# Is it threadsafe to add to a ConcurrentDictionary using foo[bar] = baz?

Tags: c#, concurrency

I'm not a fan of the methods attached to the `ConcurrentDictionary`. `AddOrUpdate` requires a func and `GetOrAdd` adds when you are just looking for the key to get the value. So I want to use it like a normal dictionary (I'm using `ContainsKey` to be safe)

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) say "To store a key/value pair in the dictionary unconditionally, and overwrite the value of a key that already exists", use The indexer's setter: `dictionary[key] = newValue`.

But is this operation still threadsafe? The comments at the bottom say "All public and protected members of ConcurrentDictionary are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads." But I'm not 100% sure that they consider the above setter to be included here.

Comment: It's a member. Is it public, protected, or private? I'm sure it's not internal.

Comment: A lock happens in the setter of `TryAddInternal` and other threads are locked out, so yes it's thread safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `indexer` implementation of `ConcurrentDictionary` at reference source -- https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs

```
    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            TValue value;
            if (!TryGetValue(key, out value))
            {
                throw new KeyNotFoundException();
            }
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            TValue dummy;
            TryAddInternal(key, value, true, true, out dummy);
        }
    }
```

If you notice the setter calls `TryAddInternal` which is thread safe implementation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is thread-safe in the sense that the internal state of the `ConcurrentDictionary` will not be corrupted. This is the main guarantee offered by this class. So if you call `foo[bar] = fiz` from one thread and `foo[bar] = biz` from another thread concurrently, then either `fiz` or `biz` will be finally stored as a value of the key `bar`, provided that this key already existed in the collection (otherwise an exception will be thrown by both threads).

It's as if `foo[bar]` was a variable with a size of a native integer or smaller, for example `short count;`. It is safe to update this variable from multiple threads, in the sense that its internal bits will not be partially updated, and will always hold the last value assigned. If this guarantee is not enough for your program, if for example you want the `count` to hold something meaningful, like how many times has been updated, then you'll have to synchronize the access to this variable.

In the case of `ConcurrentDictionary`, if you want the `foo[bar]` to hold the value `biz` only if it was previously `fiz`, then this is **not** thread-safe: `if (foo[bar] == fiz) foo[bar] = biz`. You'll have to use the [`TryUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryupdate?view=netframework-4.8) method: `foo.TryUpdate(bar, biz, fiz)`. Another case: if you want the `foo[bar]` to hold the value `biz` only if it was **not** previously `fiz`, then you are out of luck. The `ConcurrentDictionary` does not include a method that offers this guarantee. So you'll be forced to go back in using a `Dictionary` + manual synchronization.